# Closing an UIImagePickerController from a different thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiimagepickercontroller

In my multi-tab app a thread cares about listening for messages coming from the server and it must be able to close a UIImagePickerController in case the camera is active while a specific message is received. The thread is run through NSThread detachNewThreadSelector.

I managed to invoke the right sequence of calls on the thread side through the ApplicationDelegate but the picker is not dismissed:

```
- (void) closeCameraController {
    [cameraTabController closeSubViewCamera];  // Invokes cancel: on the cameraSubView.
}
```

The same sequence works properly when I start it through an event mapped on a button of the camera overlay (a 'Cancel' button):

```
- (IBAction) cancel {
    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];        
}
```

Comment: For the most part, UIKit classes are not thread safe and they should be used only from the main thread. A long running task executing in the background typically calls [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) to update the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1):

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes
>   derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your
>   application’s user interface in any way.

You can use NSObject's [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)

```
- (void) closeCameraController {
    [cameraTabController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(closeSubViewCamera) 
           withObject:nil
        waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up solving the problem using something similar to what you suggested but invoking it on the appDelegate.